Changing download location
I have a script that downloads file into a folder. The scripts works properly, but the downloads of the script are going into the my project folder. What I would like to do, is have these downloads placed into an alternate location: L:\Data\Scores\ACT
Where would I include or change this in my script? Would I need to define where the path is, or alter DOWNLOAD_DIR somehow?
I am using VS Code.
Image of where files are currently being downloaded to
import requests
import json
import os
import re
from urllib.parse import urlparse, unquote
from pathlib import Path

# SET THE API URL

URL = "https://api.datalab.nrccua.org/v1"

# SET YOUR API KEY

API_KEY = "xxxxx"

# SET YOUR ORG UID

ORGANIZATION_UID = "xxxxx"

# override this if you want

DOWNLOAD_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
DOWNLOAD_DIR = Path(DOWNLOAD_DIR)




Have you tried setting the directory you want to DOWNLOAD_DIR? If you have, what happened?

Apart from the indentation issues, the program is going to write the downloaded content to DOWNLOAD_DIR because that's where you've asked for the file to be created / written

# override this if you want

DOWNLOAD_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
DOWNLOAD_DIR = Path(DOWNLOAD_DIR)

As commented, you need to modify the path content in DOWNLOAD_DIR.
Based on the information you provided, I think you just need to modify these two lines to DOWNLOAD_DIR = Path('L:/Data/Scores/ACT').

I appreciate the explanation and guidance.
I was able to alter the download location by setting the path to a variable and it was written the right location.
x = "C:/path/would/go/here"
DOWNLOAD_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
DOWNLOAD_DIR = Path(x)

